# numpy rfftn changes input dimensions

Tags: python, numpy, fft

I want to compute the discrete Fourier Transform of a 3D numpy array. I'm using the `numpy.fft.rfftn` function but its output has different dimensions of the input, how can I fix this? 
Here it is my code:

```
np.shape(img_coll)
>>> (9997, 50, 50)
img_spectrum = np.fft.rfftn(img_coll, axes = [0])
np.shape(img_spectrum)
>>>(4999, 50, 50)
```

Thank you very much for helping.

Comment: If you want to computev the full DFT, just use `numpy.fft.fftn`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing to fix in your code.
If your signal is *real*, then its Fourier transform is *conjugate symmetric*.
In other words, the frequency-domain signal `img_spectrum` (along the first axis `axes=[0]`) has *even magnitude* and *odd phase*, so the user is responsible of reconstructing the Fourier-transformed signal.